# why did the text "swappedout://" appear in the addressbar when the page loaded?

Tags: google-chrome

i was browsing when suddenly my internet connection got disconnected. when it resumed the page that was reloading then stopped loading and i got a blank page with the text "swappedout://" in the addressbar and the title bar of the browser. can someone explain the reason? thanks in advance

Comment: Read http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/12uRRZw6tNE/8AOIb1vmVLcJ

Answer (score 3):

Happened to me just now and before. I rarely encounter this but somehow its related to the following:

- when your IP address got changed
- you release/renew IP

Its nothing to be alarmed of I think. Just refresh the page.

Some links related to this swappedout thing:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143445

Comment: -1 My IP didn't change. It's something with the memory I'd say, but I don't know what.

Comment: Hey Luc, Happy new year. Are you 100% sure your IP didnt changed?  I'm talking about "Public IP" not your local network IP address.  and is that -1 really necessary just for that?

Comment: HNY to you too! And I -1'd because it was incorrect, for me at least. It costs you 2 rep, come on :P I checked both my internal and external IP for any changes.

Comment: Well it is what happened to my case before though, I have a webpage that was trying to refresh for a long time and then I run via commandline an IP release.  Here are some more findings that was reported in chromium: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143445

Comment: Just saying, in my case the IP didn't change (neither the local one nor the router's one). I clicked the "repair connection" thing on a Windows XP machine.

Comment: I just saw this, and I have verified with 100% certainty that my public IP did not change.  I am also nearly certain that my private NAT'd IP did not change.

Refreshing the page made the symptom go away.

Comment: ok, it's somehow is just related to "networks". I also don't think a -1 downvote is appropriate just for that...

Comment: yeah -1 was a bit harsh